# Integers change its values generating time series from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a list with dataframes inside it like this:

```
 x = data.frame("city" = c("Madrid","Madrid","Madrid","Madrid"), 
 "date" = c('2018-11-01','2018-11-02','2018-11-03','2018-11-04'),
 "visits" = c(100,200,80,38), "temp"=c(20,10,17,16))     

  list_of_cities= split(x, x$city) #In my original df there are a lot of cities
```

Then, to create a time series object (ts), I follow the next process:

```
madrid_data = select(list_of_cities[['Madrid']],date,visits,temp)
madrid = ts(madrid_data[,2:3], start = c(2018,305), frequency = 365)
```

In this example, the problem I have does not arise. However, with my original dataframe I get this:
[image]

How could I solve it? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the type "integer64". It is needed to change integer64 to numeric, and in that way, everything is solved.

```
x$visits = as.numeric(x$visits)
```